# Understanding Play 2.4 Dependency Injection

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.4

I have issues to understand how to apply the new feature of Dependency Injection in Play 2.4. I'm familiar with Guice and miss in the Play Documentation an explanation how and when the actual binding is happening. I read the official docu [1] and tried to use the latest Play Mailer [2] as an example. The Play Mailer example uses an arbitrary class and annotates the `MailerClient` property with `@inject`. When I try to use an object of this class the property is `null`, at least while debugging. So, where and when do I have to do the actual injection? I have the same issue for the `@singleton` annotation. It is just explained how to annotate it, but not how to get an object. Do I have to use Guice directly, or is it integrated some how?

[1] https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection

[2] https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Its basically like the official Play Mailer Example. I initiate the `MyComponent` in another class and call the `sendMail()` method.

Comment: I'm also confused by this and would love to see some more examples out there. I'm writing some S3 code and I have an S3File object dependent on an S3Service which should be injected. How do I create a new instance of S3File with S3Service injected into it? Do I create an Injector in my controller? In that case I guess I would use 'injector.getInstance(S3File.class)'  instead of 'new S3File'? How do I create the injector - it seems like overkill to have to create a specific impl of AbstractModule to do the binding for this one class. What does the @ImplementedBy on my interface do if not this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the binding is happening through [MailerModule](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala) added to [play.modules.enabled](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L3). [MailerModule](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala) provides the Guice binding for MailerClient.

```
play {
  modules {
    enabled += "play.api.libs.mailer.MailerModule"
  }
```

For Guice to inject MailerClient into your object, it should be created through Guice.  For example, if you would like to use `@Inject MailerClient` in a Controller or a Service injected into controller, your controller needs to be injected through Guice. [Recommended approach for this in Play 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Routing) is adding the following to your build.sbt:

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what I thought. It has to be injected through Guice. I understand how this is done with the `InjectedRoutesGenerator`, because there you have some Instance, which is doing the injection. But in the documentation of the Play Mailer this is not done in a controller, but within a random class. So who is responsible then?

Comment: @linsenfips If the field MailerClient is supposed to be injected, then this 'random class' object has to be created through Guice.  Alternatively, you can manually set the field, using Constructor/Setter, if you would like to skip DI completely.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought. But still: How do I do that. The Play developers integrated Guice tightly into the framework. So what is the "official Play way" of creating a object through Guice?

Comment: @linsenfips You can create a custom Guice module to provide your bindings.  Play allows you to add your custom Guice modules using play.modules.enabled.  Please see the example in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings).  Now you are in Guice territory and there are several ways to provide your custom instances to injector; one of the options would be to create a method in your Guice module (with any name) to return MailerClient and annotate it with `@Provides`.